# Order of numbers in "between"

Tags: word-order, reading-aloud

While using between, we always use "lower"-"higher" number format. Recently, I got in argument whether this was just convention or is it standard?

> In other words, is this valid sentence: "I bought **10-5 apples** from market."

Any references related to same would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if there is a language on (the?) Earth in which it is a custom to use the downward range.

Comment: You might ask for (and add) details as to why someone though it was OK to use higher-lower.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really need references?

This is the norm, and any native speaker would instantly back up that high-low sounds absurd.

Demand references from the person suggesting that the non-conventional version is acceptable... (hint: it isn't)